# What is the problem of the emergence of the macroscopic world?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In the concluding section of [the paper](http://valbuena.fis.ucm.es/gisc/papers/nphys3230.pdf) *(Ref 1)* I'm reading, it says "we must return to Maxwell’s original concern about the second law and try to address the basic problems of statistical mechanics, such as *the emergence of the macroscopic world*".

What is the problem of *"the emergence of the macroscopic world"*?

I assume that this is a well-known problematic issue in statistical mechanics, since the problem appeared suddenly without explanation in the paper. However, I have never encountered this problem, at least not in my undergraduate studies of statistical mechanics and thermodynamics.
Of course, I did a Google search and Google Scholar for this keyword, but without any useful results.

*Ref 1.* Parrondo, Juan MR, Jordan M. Horowitz, and Takahiro Sagawa. "Thermodynamics of information." Nature physics 11.2 (2015): 131-139.